# ArangoDB Edge Modelling

Tags: arangodb

I'm modeling out my ArangoDB database and the list of edge collections I've created is growing and growing. I could just combine all of the edges into a single edge collection called **relations** with a **type** parameter. 
It would certainly clean up my list of tables but would it have any effect on my traversal queries? Would it have any positive or negative effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a **vertex-centric index** for the edge collection. This allows you to use a single edge collection without a big performance impact.

You can essentially add indexes on the "_from" or "_to" field and your `type` attribute.
If your traversal queries need both directions you need to add two indexes one on "_to"+"_type" and one on "_from"+"_type"

https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/index-and-search/indexing/working-with-indexes/vertex-centric-indexes/